Process exit hangs in __scrt_acquire_startup_lock
When my Windows CPP/CLI app calls exit(), it sometimes hangs in the CRT function __scrt_acquire_startup_lock() (see stack below).
How can I avoid this hang?
Call stack of hang
1      mylib.dll!__scrt_acquire_startup_lock() Line 148
2      mylib.dll!dllmain_crt_process_detach(const bool is_terminating) Line 172
3      mylib!dllmain_dispatch(HINSTANCE__ * const instance, const unsigned long reason, void * const reserved) Line 293
4      mscoreei.dll!_CorDllMain()
5      mscoree.dll!00007ff8d8bb1b4d()
6      mscoree.dll!00007ff8d8bb1ba7()
7      ntdll.dll!LdrpCallInitRoutine()
8      ntdll.dll!LdrShutdownProcess()
9      ntdll.dll!RtlExitUserProcess()
10     kernel32.dll!ExitProcessImplementation()
11     mscoreei.dll!RuntimeDesc::ShutdownAllActiveRuntimes(unsigned int,class RuntimeDesc *,enum RuntimeDesc::ShutdownCompatMode)
12     mscoree.dll!00007ff8d8bb719e()
13     ucrtbase.dll!try_cor_exit_process()
14     ucrtbase.dll!exit_or_terminate_process()
15     ucrtbase.dll!common_exit()
16     (my code that calls exit())

Code for dllmain_dispatch()
    if (reason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH || reason == DLL_THREAD_ATTACH)
    {
        result = dllmain_raw(instance, reason, reserved);
        if (!result)
            __leave;

        result = dllmain_crt_dispatch(instance, reason, reserved);
        if (!result)
            __leave;
    }

    result = DllMain(instance, reason, reserved);

    // If the client DllMain routine failed, unwind the initialization:
    if (reason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH && !result)
    {
        DllMain(instance, DLL_PROCESS_DETACH, reserved);
        dllmain_crt_dispatch(instance, DLL_PROCESS_DETACH, reserved);
        dllmain_raw(instance, DLL_PROCESS_DETACH, reserved);
    }

    if (reason == DLL_PROCESS_DETACH || reason == DLL_THREAD_DETACH)
    {
        result = dllmain_crt_dispatch(instance, reason, reserved);  <<<<< This call hangs
        if (!result)
            __leave;

        result = dllmain_raw(instance, reason, reserved);
        if (!result)
            __leave;
    }

